# Why do I not need a call to `add_test` in cmake?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, googletest

I've seen `add_test` a few times in `cmake` and I'm confused because I'm using `googletest` and I haven't needed a single call to `add_test`. Could somebody please explain why? Is this handled directly by `googletest` or is this call just not used when you use `googletest`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command adds a target (or custom command) to [CTest](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html). So whenenver you execute `ctest` inside the build directory, all added tests get executed. If you don't want to use CTest and simply execute your test binary manually, then there is no need to use `add_test`.

In larger projects, where tests usually consist of several binaries, it is more convenient to execute all tests using using a single command (especially when your build pipeline is automated).

Answer (score 1):

Since CMake 3.10 there is the `gtest_discover_tests()`...

ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GoogleTest.html